# Compress video by using FFMPEG

Tags: android, c++, video, ffmpeg, compression

I tried `Call C/C++ function in C/C++ file` in java file and okay.

But I don't know how I can transfer the query string in below to C/C++ function` for compressing video :

`ffmpeg -y -i /sdcard/videokit/in.mp4  -strict experimental -s 160x120 -r 25 -aspect 3:4 -vcodec mpeg4 -b 2097152 -ab 48000 -ac 2 -ar 22050 /sdcard/videokit/out.mp4`

exactly.

What I want is I can `compress the video using ffmpeg`. (I think we will call via C function in C file)

*p/s : I read many topics, many people get this issue, but no answer is satisfied.*

People who know this,

Please help me,

Thanks,

Comment: could you please tell us with more detail: (1) what you want to accomplish, (2) what have you tried, (3) what problems you found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This command converts to dozens of API calls in ffmpeg. So see what option sets what, you must read the ffmpeg.c file. Another option is to use ffmpeg.c, rename main() to something else, compile it into your program, then you can call it with a string.

Comment: The second option sounds like a really nice idea - i.e. using ffmpeg.c inside the program as you suggest. Have you actually tried this and got it to work and/or do you have any examples you could point to?